# Wordpress Tesseract theme footer copyright

Tags: php, wordpress, copyright-display

i build a website using Wordpress Tesseract theme and i want to change the copyright. I made it using Find And Replace plugin but i want to do it properly by changing the code. 
I searched it and i found the code i have to change at functions.php file.
But i do not understand the code and i am not sure if i just change the "copyright" if it will actually works, so i need some help.

function tesseract_footer_branding_output() {

```
//$str_foobclass = str_rot13(implode('',array('q','r','f','v','t','a','r','e')));
$str_foobclass = 'designer';

//$str_foobid = str_rot13(implode('',array('s','b','b','g','r','e','-','o','n','a','a','r','e','-','e','v','t','u','g')));
$str_foobid = 'footer-banner-right';

//$str_foobtby = str_rot13(implode('',array('G','u','r','z','r',' ','o','l',' ','%','f')));
$str_foobtby = 'Theme by %s';

//$str_foobturl = str_rot13(implode('',array('g','r','f','f','r','e','n','p','g','g','u','r','z','r','.','p','b','z')));
$str_foobturl = 'tesseracttheme.com';

//$str_foobtdis = str_rot13(implode('',array('G','r','f','f','r','e','n','p','g')));
$str_foobtdis = 'Tesseract';

echo '<div id="'.$str_foobid.'" class="'.$str_foobclass.'"><div class="table"><div class="table'.'-cell"><strong>';


/*if(stristr(__( $str_foobtby, 'tesseract' ),'%s') === false){

    echo '<a href="http://'.$str_foobturl.'">'.sprintf( __( $str_foobtby, 'tesseract' ),$str_foobtdis).'</a>';

}else{

    // if changes in language file
    echo '<a href="http://'.$str_foobturl.'">'.sprintf( $str_foobtby,$str_foobtdis).'</a>';

}*/

if(stristr(__( 'Theme by %s', 'tesseract' ),'%s') === false){

    echo '<a href="https://'.$str_foobturl.'">'.sprintf( __( 'Theme by %s', 'tesseract' ),$str_foobtdis).'</a>';

}else{

    // if changes in language file
    echo '<a href="https://'.$str_foobturl.'">'.sprintf( 'Theme by %s',$str_foobtdis).'</a>';

}
```

[functions.php code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76Btv.png)

As you see, in the screenshot too, in line 796, 799 and 802 if i change "Theme by %s", 'tesseracttheme.com', 'Tesseract', to something like "Copyright 2017 myname" will it be ok?

I dont understand the arrays meaning and what exactly is happening to these lines.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just change the values of the variables that are being set at the top of your script to suit your needs, as those are what's being echoed lower in the code.  However...

1. Check to ensure that this is in compliance with the license you have for this theme.
2. If you're going to alter a theme's functions.php file, create a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) from it, and alter that or your going to have problems down the road if and when you upgrade that theme.